# While uploading image how to display progress bar in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to iphone programming. Using below code I uploading image and audio in server but while uploading how to display progress bar?

```
-(void)aMethodd:(id)sender
{
      UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
indicator.center = self.button.center;
[self.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator bringSubviewToFront:tempView];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
[indicator startAnimating];

    NSString* caption = @"Aslam";
    NSString* imagepath = @"Tauky/image001.jpg";
    NSString* audiopath = @"Tauky/audio001.mp3";
    // NSString* user_id = @"45";
    NSString* user_id=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"45"];
    NSString* mobile_tauky_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];

    NSString* blauky_id = @"0";
    NSURL *dataURL=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/index.php/api/uploadClass/uploadTauky/"]];
       NSMutableURLRequest *dataRqst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [dataRqst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

    [dataRqst addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

    // -------------------- ---- caption ---------------------------\\


    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"caption\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //caption
    // -------------------- ---- userId ---------------------------\\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[user_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"%@",user_id);
    NSLog(@"Hai aslam");

    //asdf
    // -------------------- ---- mobile_tauky_id ---------------------------\\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobile_tauky_id\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[mobile_tauky_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // -------------------- ---- blauky_id ---------------------------\\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"blauky_id\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[blauky_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // media part

    // -------------------- ---- Image Upload Status ---------------------------\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *mediaType=@"Image";
    NSLog(@"type %@",mediaType);
    [postBody appendData:[mediaType dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //pass MediaType file

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image18.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // get the image data from main bundle directly into NSData object
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image18.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(SavedImage1);

    //NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Your Image);
    // add it to body
    [postBody appendData:imageData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    // -------------------- ---- Audio Upload Status ---------------------------\

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\n"
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *mediaTypee=@"tone";
    NSLog(@"type %@",mediaTypee);
    [postBody appendData:[mediaTypee dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"; filename=\"ch.mp3\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/mp3\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // get the image data from main bundle directly into NSData object
    NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ch" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:mediaPath1];
    //NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Your Image);
    // add it to body
    [postBody appendData:file1Data];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // final boundary

   [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add body to post

    [dataRqst setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;

    //synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:dataRqst returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    //convert data into string
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Response String %@",responseString);

}
```

Right now i am trying using activity indicator but here if click on upload button means after getting repsonse then its showing activity indicator.I am not getting what is the mistake.I am writing that code top its self then also its call that activity indicator after getting response form server.
And also i got some other code using that while i am downloading image or audio i can able to show progress bar using below code.Similarly i want to while uploading i want to show progress bar.Can any body tell me how to do this.

```
  bar = [[UIDownloadBar alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/uploads/28/Audio/508.mp3"]
                                            progressBarFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 200, 20)
                                         timeout:25
                                        delegate:self];

        alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]init];
        lblForDisplay=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 40, 200, 20)];
        lblForDisplay.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lblForDisplay.text=@"Downloading...";
        lblForDisplay.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        [alert addSubview:lblForDisplay];
        [alert addSubview:bar];
        [alert show];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using `AFNetworking`, specifically `AFURLConnectionOperation` as it provides a simple block callback to give you the progress.

Answer (score 1):

As @Wain Wrote there is a great networking library called AFNetworking, look for it on GitHub.

Here is an AFNetworking example:

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 120, 5)];
//when you have the image convert it to NSData:
NSData *fileData = image?UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0):nil

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURL.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];


NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                            fromData:fileData
                            progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                                // This is not called back on the main queue.
                                // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    //Update the progress view
                                    [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];                 
                                });
                            }

                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, id responseObject, NSError* error) {

                       if (error) {
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                       } else {
                           NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                       }

                   }];

[uploadTask resume];
```